# IUserPromptService message when trying to create an attribute relationship in Visual Studio (Microsoft Tutorial)

Tags: windows-services, visual-studio-2022

I'm going through the Microsoft Multidimensional Modeling (Adventure Works Tutorial) and have come across the following error message when I try to create a new attribute relationship. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything. I'm using the 2022 version of Visual Studio and the 2019 version of SSMS. I am connected through the localhost account (but had to use a specific Windows user name and password as it would not deploy through the service account). Any thoughts?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrjDD.png)

===================================

Service provider has to support IUserPromptServive! (Microsoft Visual Studio)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.AR.EditRelationshipsDataProvider.Init(Dimension inDimension, IServiceProvider inServiceProvider)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.AR.EditRelationshipsDataProvider..ctor(Dimension inDimension, DimensionAttribute inAttribute, IServiceProvider inServiceProvider)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.AR.CommonMenuHandlers.CreateAttributeRelationship(MenuCommand menuCommand, CommandHandlingArgs args)
at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.CommandHandlingInfoMap.HandleCommand(MenuCommand menuCommand)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.AR.CommonMenuHandlers.InvokeCommand(MenuCommand menuCommand)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for information about the same problem, I found that this is a bug of VS 2022

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/service-provider-has-to-support-iuserpromptservive/1648082

To avoid this problem, the option is to use VS 2019 until Microsoft releases an update of VS 2022 with the fix

Comment: I'm using VS2019 16.11.26 and I'm still having this issue